# Running batch FOR loop in directory with brackets

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I'm having issues when running this batch in a directory with brackets in the name (files not being deleted) and was looking for some help.

```
for /f "eol=; tokens=*" %%a in (old_file_list.txt) do (
  cd /d %~dp0\mods
  IF EXIST "%%a" del %%a
  cd /d %~dp0
)

for /f "eol=; tokens=*" %%a in (old_file_list.txt) do (
  cd /d %~dp0\config
  IF EXIST "%%a" del %%a
  cd /d %~dp0
)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not doing this in PowerShell?

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker - Because he wants to be able to simply double-click the script to make it run instead of spending time configuring his system and every other system he might want to run the script on.

Comment: I have no experience in PowerShell.

Comment: When you say brackets, do you mean `[]`, `{}`, or `<>`?

Comment: By  brackets I mean ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There's no need repeat "enter -> del -> quit" cycle, you can just test file under subdir and delete files from there.
2. It's better to place double quotes when use pathes.

Try this:

```
for /f "eol=; tokens=*" %%a in (old_file_list.txt) do (
  IF EXIST "%~dp0\mods\%%a" del "%~dp0\mods\%%a"
  IF EXIST "%~dp0\config\%%a" del "%~dp0\config\%%a"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still having issues with the files not being deleted (text file not being read?) when running in a directory with brackets in the name.

Comment: @Agent_adam99 - Are you sure? POW's code should work unless your file names begin with `;`. Or it could fail if your `mods` and `config` folders are not in the same folder as your batch script, in which case your logic is completely wrong.

Comment: @Agent_adam99 - There also is no need to check if the file exists. You could simply delete always while redirecting stderr to nul using `2>nul` - The file will be deleted if it exists, or nothing will happen if it doesn't.